# How to specify python arguments except 0th argument

Tags: python, argument-passing

If you call python with arguments, i.e.

```
python script.ps arg1, arg2, arg2
```

sys.argv[0] is script.ps, the name of the script

How do I reference and save the value of ALL arguments of a python script except the 0th argument.

Here is my script

```
import sys, subprocess, socket, string
import wmi, win32api, win32con

for args in [item.strip('sender-ip=') for item in sys.argv[1:]]:

    userIP = args
    userloggedon = ""

    # perform system lookup of IP address
    userIP = "\\\\" + userIP

    pst = subprocess.Popen(
            ["D:\pstools\psloggedon.exe", "-l", "-x",  userIP],
            stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr = subprocess.PIPE
        )

    out, error = pst.communicate()

    userLoggedOn = out.split('\n')[1].strip()
    print 'userId={}'.format(userLoggedOn)
```

This script works perfectly if I sender-ip is the only argument, i.e.

```
python script.ps sender-ip=10.10.10.10
```

but if I invoke it with

```
python script.ps email=joe@gmail.com, sender-ip=10.10.10.10
```

or

```
python script.ps email=joe@gmail.com sender-ip=10.10.10.10
```

or

```
python script.ps "email=joe@gmail.com, sender-ip=10.10.10.10"
```

you get the idea......

it doesn't work because it fails to extract the IP address from sender-ip.

The output I expect is

```
userId=DOMAIN\username
```

instead I get

```
userId=
```

or

```
userId=
userId=DOMAIN\username
```

Comment: You should probably look into [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html).

Comment: in the way you call the script why not to use kwargs instead?

Comment: IF my answer solved your problem accept it so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argparse` can help you out in such circumstances and it's a very useful tool to have under your belt.

Here's an `argparse` example with multiple args:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Description of your program')
parser.add_argument('-f','--foo', help='Description for foo argument', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-b','--bar', help='Description for bar argument', required=True)
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
```

`args` will be a dictionary containing the arguments:

```
if args['foo'] == 'Hello':
    pass # replace with code

if args['bar'] == 'World':
    pass # replace with code
```

Also check here for more information:

- [argparse documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html)

**Edit:** For positional arguments(e.g. pos_arg=value) use:

```
parser.add_argument('pos_arg', nargs='+', help='Description for positional argument')
```

Comment: Why are you calling `vars()` on the result of `parse_args()`?  Just do `args.foo == 'Hello'`, which is also more readable.

Comment: What happens if I want to parametrize the argument? I would have to use `getattr(args, argvar) where argvar = foo`. It's a trade-off between adding initial readability and removing eventual readability

Comment: Except that you almost never parametrize over attributes. So you are decreasing readability of a very common operation to slightly increase readability of a very uncommon one.

Comment: It's not only that but, this allows args to be passed as **keyword argument for further processing. Making it a dictionary allows more flexibility. I'd rather not use a hardcoded attribute access. If you do, I won't hold it against you it's a matter of preference.

Comment: @TamerTas --- Right now I'm trying to see how it can work such that it reads sender-ip=[any ip address], and extracts the value of "any IP address"

Comment: `parser.add_argument('sender-ip','--sender-ip', help='Description for bar argument', required=True)` should be able to do what you're asking.

Comment: @TamerTas when I try and I call the program with python argss.py sender-ip=10.10.10.10 I get the errors ... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "argss.py", line 4, in <module>
    parser.add_argument('sender-ip','--sender-ip', help='Description for sender-
ip argument', required=True)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\argparse.py", line 1267, in add_argument
    kwargs = self._get_optional_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\argparse.py", line 1397, in _get_optional_kwargs
    raise ValueError(msg % tup)
ValueError: invalid option string 'sender-ip': must start with a character '-'